# rbt status returns 401 Authorization Required

Tags: macos, ldap, review-board

My Review Board instance uses LDAP for authentication, logging in via the web UI works just fine. I'm trying to setup `rbt` command line tools on my Mac. Despite entering my username and password correctly, it claims to fail with `401 Authorization Required`

```
rbt status --username redacted

Please log in to the Review Board server at redacted.com.
Password: 
CRITICAL: HTTP 401
```

Any pointers? Is this something with my environment or LDAP setup?

Comment: This might be too late but what is the version of RBtools that you are using? Please look at the following bug - "https://hellosplat.com/s/beanbag/tickets/3203/" Can you post apache logs?